# Can there exist an uncountable collection of independent Bernoulli random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

So it's quite obvious that a countably infinite collection of independent Bernoulli random variables exists but as always uncountability complicates the matter.

For similar questions about uncountable collections of non-constant random variables on $[0,1]$ the answer is no, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1549807/showing-that-there-do-not-exist-uncountably-many-independent-non-constant-rando). But I could not find any resources talking about uncountable collections of Bernoulli random variables.

Comment: Bernoulli random variables are non-constant if $0<p<1$ so the statement in  the linked question applies to such variables as well. But it is also limited to a particular probability space. The choice of probability space is a vital part of the statement. Are we allowed to choose a different one?

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear whether you are interested only in random variables on $(0,1)$ or any probability space will do. Given any collection of distribution functions $\{F_i\}_{i \in I}$ we can construct independent random variables $\{X_i\}_{i \in I}$ such that $X_i$ has distribution $F_i$ for each $i$. Kolomogorov's Consistency Theorem covers this and even more general constructions.